# Codeigniter PHP require_once works but load->view doesn't

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing a weird problem for 1 hour, I searched it on internet and this forum but couldn't find the Solution that I am looking for. I am using codeigniter framework to develop a small product. So here is my problem:

I have a controller named `music.php` which simply loads the template view:

```
/* music.php */
public function index()
{
    $data['main_content'] = 'admin/music/list';
    $this->load->view('admin/template', $data);  
}
```

The content of `admin/template.php` is as follows

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

the `header.php` and `footer.php` are located on the same folder as `template.php`. Now when I tried to access the file, browser shows the error `"Unable to load the requested file: header.php"`. But instead if I use `require_once("header.php")` it works fine. Can any one solve this problem

**Edit 1**: my `route.php` is

```
$route['default_controller'] = "homepage";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['admin'] = 'admin/music';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All calls to `load->view()` use paths relative to `application/views`, not relative to the file calling it. (They also do not take your routes into consideration at all)

If `header.php` and `footer.php` are located in the same folder as `template.php` (the master template you are loading) you still need to reference the full path, starting with `admin/`:

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('admin/footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are right. But this answer is for the ones who are using codeigniter 4. You need to do the following:

```
<?php echo view('admin/header'); ?>
<?php echo view($maincontent); ?>
<?php echo view('admin/footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

From above code, it seems you have `header.php` `and footer.php` file in your `application/view/admin/` folder. Therefore use :

```
<?php $this->load->view('admin/header'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('admin/footer'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I assume it has to do with the missing constructor function. At least, this solved the problem for me. Add this as first function in your controller:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```